# axios request to node.js server not returning data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, http-status-code-404, router

Edit: Just a typo that I missed.
I apologize. Thank you Alexander

I am not getting response data in my client.
However when I use postman, I get the data i need.
On console I get the following error.
Any idea why I am getting this problem?

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61) "error"
```

Server-side

```
const express = require("express");
const genreData = require("../data/genreData.json")
const fs = require ('fs')
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (_, res) => {
    res.json(genreData);
  });

router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    res.json(genreData.find(user => user.id == req.params.id))
})
 module.exports = router;
```

Client-side

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export class Result extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props) 
            this.state = {
                user: {}
            }
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        axios.get(`http:/localhost:8001/genre/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(res => 
            this.setState({user: res.data}))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error, "error")
        })
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.user)
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.user.id}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Result
```

Postman get request to http://localhost:8001/genre/52163492-5e66-4bbf-a3dc-2b8120e3afe8

```
{
    "id": "52163492-5e66-4bbf-a3dc-2b8120e3afe8",
    "action": 3,
    "anime": 4,
    "children": 5,
    "comedy": 2,
    "documentary": 4,
    "drama": 5,
    "horror": 5,
    "musical": 5,
    "scifi": 5,
    "thriller": 5
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `this.props.match.params.id`?

Comment: `http:/` should be `http://` unless that's a typo you are missing a `/` character.

Answer (score 0):

add `console.log(this.props.match.params.id)` to componentDidMount() to see if you have correct Id

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same code you are running? I think you have a typo error

axios.get(`http:/localhost:8001/genre/${this.props.match.params.id}`)

Please add // after http.